# Difference tax rate for different day on same product

Tags: php, woocommerce, tax

How I set such of conditional tax rate on woo-commerce

$65 all day plus tax and drop off $15 drop-off which comes to $86.28 
Monday Thursday excluding holidays and weekends

2hrs $49 plus tax and drop off $15 which comes to $69.02 
Monday Thursday

Friday Saturday Sunday call for pricing subject to change

Comment: Technically speaking this sounds like a conditional *price* rather than tax rate

Comment: Is it possible to set new price by php case methods?